# TypeError: XXX undefined with AngularJS inline array annotation

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Im making an AngularJS Application and Im trying to insert JSONwebtoken into the headers, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Can you guys help me out?

My application config:

```
application.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $localStorage, $window, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');

}]);
```

And my AuthInterceptors factory:

```
application.factory("AuthInterceptors", function(AuthToken) {
  var authInterceptorsFactory = {};

    authInterceptorsFactory.request = function(config) {

      var token = AuthToken.getToken();

      if(token) config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;

      return config;
    };

  return authInterceptorsFactory;
});
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your order of dependencies is not correct in your function. You have to keep the same order of dependencies in your function and in your annotations,

```
application.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptors');

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ## Inline Array Annotation
>
> When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependence Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation)

This problem can be avoided by using [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation). Tools like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) let you use implicit dependency annotations in your app and automatically add inline array annotations prior to minifying.